# NuGet force update of dependency packages in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package

I have currently installed the NuGet packages Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base version 32.961.0 and Xamarin.Forms version 3.0.0.561731. Now I want to update Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base to the newest version 60.1142.1, but I can't because it has a dependency NuGet package Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 26.0.2) which is also da dependency of Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.561731. On the other hand, Xamarin.Forms has a dependency to the same package via Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 25.4.0.2).

I get the following version conflict in VS:

```
 MyApp.Android -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 26.0.2) 
 MyApp.Android -> Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.561731 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2).
```

If I could just force an update of dependency package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 to the newest version, then it would also require a newer version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat and the conflicts are gone.

Comment: Uninstall any `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.***` packages that you have added, ensure the you are targeting the MonoDroid 8.1 framework, now perform an update on the `Xamarin.Android` packages to get the latest `Xamarin.Android.Support.XXX` versions, now install the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.XXX` package(s) that you need (FYI: typically you do install the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` as a standalone, but via one of the other Play services (or Firebase) packages.

Comment: You could delete the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 & Compat folders from C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Xamarin in order to force the update on the startup of VS

Comment: @chrs.zrkl, Any update for this issue now? Have you check my updated answer? I have test it, and it works fine on my side, let me know if it not works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NuGet force update of dependency packages in Visual Studio

Just like the error shows:

> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1 ->
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.1 ->
>   **Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 26.0.2)**
>
> Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.561731 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2
>   -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (**= 25.4.0.2**).

we could to know the version conflict comes from **Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 26.0.2)** and **Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2)**. Then check the dependencies info about package `Xamarin.Forms`, we could to know `Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.561731` -> `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` (**>= 25.4.0.2**).

So, to resolve this issue, we just need update package `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` to version **26.0.2**, which have dependency Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (**26.0.2**).

To accomplish this, uninstall the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` packages that you have added, then **update those Xamarin.Android.Support.XXX packages manually**:

Details steps:

1. Unload your projects and edit it.
2. Change the version of those Xamarin.Android.Support.XXX packages to 26.0.2:

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="3.0.0.561731" />
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="26.0.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="26.0.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="26.0.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="26.0.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="26.0.2" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
3. Reload the project, then add the package `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1`

With this way, you can update `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` to the newest version `60.1142.1`.

**update:**

> Why does XF request Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2, when the
>   docs say >= 25.4.0.2?

You may need check my above steps again, **do not** install the package `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` before updating those  `Xamarin.Android.Support.xx` packages.

That because if you install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (60.1142.1)` first, NuGet will add its dependency `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` (**>=26.0.2**).

**However**, when you install the package `Xamarin.Forms (3.1.0.583944)`, NuGet will add the lowest version dependencies by default.

Doc: [How NuGet resolves package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution)

So, NuGet will add the `Xamarin.Android.Support.xx 25.4.0.2`. And that is the reason why doc say `>= 25.4.0.2` but NuGet add version 25.4.0.2. Of course, since doc say `>= 25.4.0.2`, you could update the dependencies `Xamarin.Android.Support.xx` to `26.0.2`.

So **the solution** is:

1. Uninstall the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` packages, do **NOT** install it again immediately.
2. Install packages `Xamarin.Forms (3.1.0.583944)`, and update those `Xamarin.Android.Support.xx 25.4.0.2` to `26.0.2`(**Check above Details steps**).
3. Add the package `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did uninstall all Xamarin.* packages and re-installed Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (60.1142.1), Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 & Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (27.0.2.1). Now, I want to install Xamarin.Forms (3.1.0.583944), but I still get that error: 
    MyApp.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI (= 27.0.2.1) 
     MyApp.Android -> Xamarin.Forms 3.1.0.583944 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI (= 25.4.0.2).
Why does XF request Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2, when the docs say >= 25.4.0.2?

Comment: @chrs.zrkl, you should not install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` before  updating those `Xamarin.Android.Support.xx` packages. Check my **update:** answer for more details.